# How do I check only one radio button without changing the input name?

Tags: html, radio-button, checked

I need only one radio button checked without changing the input name.

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="radiobox_item_type">
    <li>
        <input name="item_type" value="clear" type="radio" id="radiobox_my" /> 
        <label for="radiobox">Without</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="item_new" value="new" type="radio" id="radiobox_my"  /> 
        <label>News</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="item_action" value="action" type="radio" id="radiobox_my" /> 
        <label for="radiobox2">Action</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's been a while since you asked the question, but if the problem has not been solved yet, I can write you a Javascript with which you can change the names of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Try giving all of the radio buttons the same name.

Comment: It won't work if you don't change the input name.  It's how the page knows it's a single group and not three groups.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,if you want to select only one radio button you should be same all radio button `name`

```
<ul class="radiobox_item_type">
            <li>
            <input name="item_type" value="clear" type="radio" id="radiobox_my" /> 
            <label for="radiobox">Without</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <input name="item_type" value="new" type="radio" id="radiobox_my"  /> 
            <label>News</label>
            </li>
            <li>
            <input name="item_type" value="action" type="radio" id="radiobox_my" /> 
            <label for="radiobox2">Action</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: think need some JS.. I can't change input name

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same id on all three radio buttons. If all three buttons are part of the same group then you have to give them all the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with the other answers that the best practice would be to have all the radio buttons in a group have the same name. In answer to your specific question, however, here is a jQuery solution that ensures that only one radio is selected at a time, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9smfh/):

```
var $container = $(".radiobox_item_type");
$container.on("click","input[type='radio']", function(){
    //uncheck other radio buttons
    $container.find('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
    });
    //check this radio button
    $(this).prop('checked',true);        
});
```

Basically, a click listener is added to the parent that checks if the radio buttons inside are clicked. When clicked, it unchecks all other radio buttons in the container and then checks the one that was clicked.